Issues trying to add an attribute to a restricted element in XML
I had an XML/XSD that were working fine. But I wanted to change the file by adding an ID attribute to several of the elements. I have spent hours trying various ways to get a valid xsd/xml file, but nothing is working and I do not know where i am going wrong.
Essentially, I have restricted elements that must contain a specific value. I want to add an ID to each of these elements.
I modified the Sprocket and Widget from a simpleType to a complexType and added the attribute to them. Ideally, I would like the ID to be a ref to a seperate entry, but I could not get that to work either.
The error message I get with the current file is:
31:37   s4s-elt-invalid-content.1: The content of '#AnonType_Widget' is invalid. Element 'restriction' is invalid, misplaced, or occurs too often.
49:37   s4s-elt-invalid-content.1: The content of '#AnonType_Sprocket' is invalid. Element 'restriction' is invalid, misplaced, or occurs too often.

These errors are on the restrictions in the Widget and Sprocket elements.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Configuration xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="test.xsd">
    <Widgets>
       <Widget ID="0">A</Widget>
       <Widget ID="1">B</Widget>
    </Widgets>
    <Sprockets>
        <Sprocket ID="0">X</Sprocket>
        <Sprocket ID="1">Y</Sprocket>
    </Sprockets>
</Configuration>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    
    <xs:element name="Configuration">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="Widgets" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                <xs:element ref="Sprockets" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    
    <xs:element name="Widgets">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="Widget" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    
    <xs:element name="Sprockets">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="Sprocket" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    
    <xs:element name="Widget">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xs:enumeration value="A"/>
                <xs:enumeration value="B"/>
                <xs:enumeration value="C"/>
            </xs:restriction>
            <xs:attribute name="ID" use="optional">
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                        <xs:pattern value="([0-9])*"/>
                        <xs:minLength value="1"/>
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:attribute>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:element name="Sprocket">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xs:enumeration value="X"/>
                <xs:enumeration value="Y"/>
                <xs:enumeration value="Z"/>
            </xs:restriction>
            <xs:attribute name="ID" use="required">
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                        <xs:pattern value="([0-9])*"/>
                        <xs:minLength value="1"/>
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:attribute>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

</xs:schema>


I have tried to create a simpleType within a complexType, I have tried to create a ref to the ID entry, and various combinations of modifying the simple/complex tags and adding in sequence, but I couldn't figure it out.
These are the files that I started from. I had tried to follow the simple attribute addition. I changed from simpleType to complexType. It didn't seem to accept it. Once I did that it said that my restriction tag was out of place. I don't know why.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Configuration xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="test.xsd">
    <Widgets>
       <Widget>A</Widget>
       <Widget>B</Widget>
    </Widgets>
    <Sprockets>
        <Sprocket>X</Sprocket>
        <Sprocket>Y</Sprocket>
    </Sprockets>
</Configuration>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    
    <xs:element name="Configuration">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="Widgets" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                <xs:element ref="Sprockets" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    
    <xs:element name="Widgets">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="Widget" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    
    <xs:element name="Sprockets">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="Sprocket" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    
    <xs:element name="Widget">
        <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xs:enumeration value="A"/>
                <xs:enumeration value="B"/>
                <xs:enumeration value="C"/>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:element name="Sprocket">
        <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xs:enumeration value="X"/>
                <xs:enumeration value="Y"/>
                <xs:enumeration value="Z"/>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>


While asking an XSD question you need to provide a minimal reproducible example:
(1) Well-formed input XML.
(2) Your logic, and complete executable XSD(s) that tries to implement it.
(3) XSD processor and its conformance with the XSD standards: 1.0, or 1.1.

See https://www.w3schools.com/xml/schema_simple_attributes.asp
